# php regex does not contain any of the following words

Tags: php, regex

Im using the following regex to check if a string contains any of the following words:

```
/(work|hello|yes)/
```

How could I reverse it, to check if the string instead does not contain any of the following words?

```
if (preg_match('/(work|hello|yes)/', trim(strtolower($mystring)))) {

}
```

Note I dont want to use `!preg_match`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use a negative [looakhead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match the string, if it does not contain the words:

```
^(?!.*?(?:work|hello|yes)).*
```

Also might want to add `\b` [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), before/after the word.

[Test at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/oP2iS7/1)

---

If it's multiline input, use with `s` (PCRE_DOTALL) [flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to make the `.` also match newlines.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes, I used  `.*` to select all string, if it matches.

Comment: no, it's not necessay, `^(?!.*?(?:work|hello|yes))` matches the start of a line where the following conditions are satisfied. So you don't need to match the following characters. We are just checking for a match or not.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Absolutely, that's what I said, but you can see it better for testing on regex101 and would get `$out[0]` a whole match if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You missed `'`  first parameter of preg_match

```
$mystring='hello world';
if (preg_match('/(work|hello|yes)/', trim(strtolower($mystring)))) {
    echo 'Yes'; //Result is yes
}else{
    echo 'No';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 $match    = '/work|hello|yes/';
 $myString =  trim(strtolower($mystring));

 if (preg_match($match,$myString)) {

 }
```